# accessing FormControl in Angular 2

Tags: angular

What is the difference between template variable spy and name in following two statements? What does spy represent and what does name represent. The code is from following tutorial on Angular.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
  required
  [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
  #spy>
<br>TODO: remove this: {{spy.className}}
spy is assigned value of control which represents the input.



<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               required
               [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
               #name="ngModel">
```

I thought that spy represents the FormControl within NgForm to represent the input element. Using spy, I can access properties of the FormControl (eg spyu.className). But I couldn't understand if name is also a FormControl and how assigning it a value of "ngModel" makes it different from spy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does spy represent

When you specify template reference by itself like this `#some-name`, it by default references [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) in a component/directive class and native DOM element in the template. `ElementRef` is a wrapper around native DOM element and you can read more about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02). `className` is a standard DOM API that is a string of all classes attached to the element.

If it's used by itself on the child component, it by default references component instance.

> what does name represent

When you specify template reference in the form `#some-name="other-name"`, it references a directive by the name `other-name`. So in your case:

```
#name="ngModel"
```

it references `NgModel` directive instance on this input control.

> I thought that spy represents the FormControl within NgForm to
>   represent the input element.

No, as I explained earlier, it represents `ElementRef`. To get access to the form control through template reference, you would have to use [FormControlDirective](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlDirective-directive.html) and use template reference like this:

```
<input #spy="ngForm" [formControl]="control">
```

As this directive is defined like this:

```
@Directive({selector: '[formControl]', providers: [formControlBinding], exportAs: 'ngForm'})

                                      ---------------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^

export class FormControlDirective extends NgControl implements OnChanges {
```

But that wouldn't make much sense as you would already have access to the form control in your component `control` value.

Comment: What the instance wil be referenced if i write `<child #spy></child>` where `child` is my custom component?

Comment: @yurzui, component instance, I'll add that to the answer, thanks

Comment: What is the easiest way to check what's the instance points to template reference variable? Thanks:)

Comment: @yurzui, what do you mean? can you clarify?

Comment: How do you know that `spy` in `<div #spy` will point to `HTMLDivElement` in template?

Comment: @yurzui, there are the following [queryValueTypes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/view/types.ts#L213). When compiling a template the compiler defines for each elementDef which query types it will match.  Then [getQueryValue](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/view/query.ts#L169) function uses this information to retrieve correct reference

Comment: It's too deep:) Thanks again. I meant `{{spy.constructor.name }}` or `<button (click)="check(spy)">Test</button>` and inside `check` method we can determine what type `spy` variable points to

Comment: @yurzui, ah, I see, ok :). I assume that would be helpful for demonstration purposes only. As you know, JS is not really type based. Do you use anything like that in the actual production code?